# Computer starts on it's own?

Tags: power-supply

This is a bit creepy, when I sleep at the night and BOOM, I hear my computers fan to start at their own and the computer loads. Also, many times it crashes and doesn't response to mouse/keyboard after sleep.

I replaced the PSU, but nothing changed. What is responsible for this?

Comment: Do you mean _the computer loads from halted_? Power up on LAN may be active and you being victim of a joke.

Comment: I mean i shut it down and hear the pc start (i think it starts and stays in sleep mode immediately). I will check power on lan... Is it possible to use power on lan from the internet?

Comment: Okay, *wake on lan* is *automatic*, and also *after power loss* is *last state*. I also have blue screens (not many). Maybe something is dying?

Comment: If you command it to shut down and then it restarts staying in sleep mode until it boots later, I don't think there could be a so pissed off BIOS, I would suspect the OS if is it provided by Microsoft.

Comment: Shuts down, a few hours pass and in some cases, in starts.

Answer (score 1):

Disable **Wake up on LAN** if you do not need it. A network printer could be querying the PC and waking it up.

Comment: I don't have one, but I disable it. In a few hours I will report back.

Comment: Maybe a cellphone, depending on what you could have configured on it. Also from Internet (less likely) or from other LAN objects. Could depend on your possible WLAN protection and router configuration.

Comment: smart, I will never thought about a cellphone!